# Deployment of Qt app when sources change frequently

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, compilation, mingw32

I'm currently working on a GUI app that is supposed to decrypt some data and print it on the screen, on Windows and Qt (C++) based. The **code works fine** and I now have to distribute it.

However, the format of the data to decipher **can (and will) evolve**, and is described on **headers** (.h) and **sources** (.c). Therefore, when this happens, I just have to change these files to the last version, the compilation goes fine and the program runs smoothly. It's a simple drag&drop of the new files in my source folder, really.

I am aware of how to deploy a .exe (with the correct dll and so forth), but I don't think it would work in this case. I briefly looked at how to create installers but i'm not sure that this is the right way to handle the situation (http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-creating-installers.html).

How could I distribute this code so that people that want to use it can just change the sources, run a script, and the .exe is generated, **even with a computer that does not have Qt** ? (but probably mingw32 and only on Windows)

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: You think you will still need to build the program as end-users would have to install the complete tool chain and maintain it.  I suggest you look into self-updating programs, an example of which is the Steam client from Valve, there are many other examples out there.  The other approach you could take is a modular architecture delivering the changed components as dynamic runtime modules.

Comment: I'll try and go with self-updating programs, thanks for the tip ! For what I gathered from that, I'll still have to compile on my computer then distribute it right ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you should include dll's and if the format of the data changes, you can just update and maintain your dll's.

Build your project in release mode and then use QTWinDeploy to finalize the build of the project with all the dependencys the projects require for users without QT. 
This is how I maintain and distribute a project similar to yours.

Otherwise, I would recommend looking at self-updating programs.

Comment: Thanks, but concerning the dll's, it' really not an issue, my concern is more about building the project, isn't there any way to compile the code on a computer that doesn't have Qt ? I'll definitely look at self-updating programs

Comment: I don't know of a particular method to be honest, the projects I developed in QT and distributed to my group the people who maintain them also have QT installed. You can distribute the executable to people without QT by utilizing QTWinDeploy. All the dependencys will be built with the project so that they may run the executable. Sorry if my answers weren't what you were looking for